# URL routes for Lumen (Laravel) and script paths on Homestead

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, homestead, lumen

I am building an app with Lumen for the backend and angular for the frontend. Lumen handles routes and serves the basic templates with a header and footer, where angular takes over to control the content. I am trying to add a url parameter to a route, but it breaks all my paths to scripts as it sees it as a subdirectory not a parameter. My route looks like this in Lumen:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function($app) {
    $app->get('{any}', function() {
        return view('index');
    });
    $app->get('detail/{userId}', function() {
        return view('index');
    });
});
```

I have a url of example.com/user/create that works fine, but as soon as I use example.com/user/detail/101 it breaks. How do I set it up so all my angular paths are not destroyed as I add parameters? I would like to stay away from adding the absolute url path as I really don't want to manage differing urls through dev/stage/production environments.

EDIT:
The following routes work and do not break css/script paths:
    example.com/user
    example.com/user/create

The following route does break paths:
    example.com/user/detail/101

Answer (score 1):

Add the `any` route after the `detail/{userId}` route.

In general, any "catch-all" routes need to go at the end so they don't interfere with anything.

Comment: Even moving the any route below the detail/{userId} still results in broken paths.

Comment: Are you caching your routes?

Comment: Don't think so. Even if I was, I made sure and cleared the cache after changes.